# Typescript number array no errors if empty

Tags: typescript

Why this code gives no error?

```
type X = number[];

let z: X = [];
```

Empty array is not the same as array of numbers

Comment: [Every element of the array is a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), so there is no problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array types, such as `number[]`, don't imply anything about the `.length` property. It just means that every element in the array is a number. If the length is 0, then "every element" means zero elements. The `number` indicator is still useful though, since it defines what sorts of things you're allowed to add to the array.

The type `[]` is actually a ["tuple" type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), not just an array type. Tuples specify the length property and the type found at each index, which may be different from index to index. `[]` is a rather trivial tuple, with no elements and thus a length of 0. While tuples and arrays have some similarities, array types will not automatically become tuple types.

So when you write a line of code like this:

```
let x: /**insert type here **/ = [];
```

You can pick from several different types, depending on how strict you want to be. If you want the array to contain 0 or more numbers, use `number[]`. If you want it to be a zero length array (forever), use `[]`.

Comment: This answer does not include the type for "one or more".

Answer (score 1):

The array is empty. All the elements still "are" `number` (there is none).

If you want "one or more `number`", use `[number, ...number]`.